# Django form not selecting options

Tags: python, django

I have a django project, in the project i have a django forms.py which contain a field call category which select box input element that is generated as a result of a query on the database.
If I choose an option from the select dropdown from the database I keep getting the error:

```
**strong text**Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices
```

Below is the code:

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from signer.models import CreateSingleSigner

class CreateSingleSignerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required = True,
        help_text = 'category', 
        queryset=CreateSingleSigner.objects.all().values_list(
                'category', flat=True
            ).distinct()
    )
```

my views.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from signer.models import CreateSingleSigner
from signer.forms import CreateSingleSignerForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def singlesigner(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        createsinglesigner_form = CreateSingleSignerForm(data=request.POST)
        if createsinglesigner_form.is_valid():  
            createsinglesigner.category = request.POST['category']
            createsinglesigner_form.save()
        else:
            print createsinglesigner_form.errors
    else:
        # context['createsinglesigner'] = CreateSingleSigner()
        createsinglesigner_form =CreateSingleSignerForm()

    return render(request, "signer/singlesigner.html", {"createsinglesigner_form":createsinglesigner_form}, RequestContext(request))
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class CreateSingleSigner(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Provide template code related to rendering options..

Comment: Also what value of  `form.non_field_errors` after validating forms ?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of ways below to fix problem:

1. Try to define conversion of unicode in your `CreateSingleSigner` model:

   ```
   class CreateSingleSignerForm(forms.Form):

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self. category
   ```

**Explanations**:
`ModelChoiceField` will use `__unicode__` representation of specified fields for displaying and validating your fields.

2. Try to set choices in `__init__` method of your form

   ```
   class CreateSingleSignerForm(forms.Form):
       category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=False)

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(CreateSingleSignerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['category'].choices = CreateSingleSigner.objects.all().values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
   ```

   **Explanations:** The **queryset** parameter for `ModelChoiceField` cannot be `values_list`, because it's going to save the relationships, so django have to use complete model objects, not certain values of model objects.

Comment: still having "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices"

Comment: Also what value of `createsinglesigner_form.non_field_errors` after calling `createsinglesigner_form.is_valid`?

Comment: How do i add Foreign key to these line of code:  category = forms.ModelChoiceField(required = True, help_text = 'category', queryset=CreateSingleSigner.objects.all().values_list('category', flat=True).distinct())